# Swipe To Push View Controller Like Whatsapp messages details

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewanimation

i want to ask what is the best way we need to work when we want to pan a view to push view controller, we want to make something similar like whatsapp messages status view like the following photo

[image]

we try swipe gesture and also pan gesture but we want to make same animation like what happen on whatsapp

so please can you help me?

waiting your responses

thanks

Comment: What makes one way the best of all?

Comment: Try to add Swipe gesture recognizer to each UITableViewCell or maybe detect which cell is selected when user make swipe from right to left. Maybe you need to trigger a Segue with the “swipe” animation like I. WhatsApp